# AWS Pinpoint Two way SMS is not triggering SNS for Incoming SMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I have requested a `dedicated long code`. But Whenever I send `SMS` to this Dedicated long code with `Keywords`, nothing is happening. I am not receiving any automated response messages (Response messages setup in the `AWS Pinpoint` Console). The dedicated number is for `INDIA` and region is `AWS MUMBAI REGION`.

I have also created SNS which is not at all getting triggered for incoming SMS for this dedicated number. I will provide additional details, if wanted.     Please guide me to debug this issue.

Comment: I had this same exact issue where nothing seemed to be working.  Then the next day I tried it again and everything worked fine.  Then later the next day, I start getting responses and SNS messages published for things that I had sent > 24 hours previously.   We are just prototyping with it now but I have reached out to AWS Support about this issue about 4-5 days ago and they have not responded back.  I would encourage you to also contact AWS Support (Support in the top-left corner of AWS) to report this issue.  I will reply if I get any response from them.  This was in us-east-1 and us-west-2.

Comment: @JD D Thank you for responding. My problem is in ap-south-1. It took 3 days to get dedicated long code from support center. Will it be active right away after getting the number? Or will it take time get active?

Comment: And what is the easiest way to check number is working? I tried Sending HELP keyword with my own phone number to dedicated long number. Nothing is happening. I should get the response message right? Is it right way to check it?

Comment: Yes, I believe it should be the right way.  If you have enabled self-managed opt-out then you won't receive responses from HELP or STOP but you should receive responses from your user-defined keywords.  You should be able to use the long code immediately after you received this.  I have had success with using long codes immediately after they are issued but then again I have experienced day-long periods of no response that I still have not been able to track down yet.

Comment: I have few doubts regarding this AWS pinpoint, is it possible for you to chat with me for few minutes if you don't mind? I will provide my email id.

Comment: we can chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193966/pinpoint-issues

Comment: It says i need to be logged in to chat. But I am already logged in.

Comment: There is no message box to send messages there in the chat. Looks like the chat room is readonly

Comment: @JDD I am already logged in, it the link say I need to be logged in to chat. I can see your message in the chat. But I am not able to send message as I can't see any box to send

Comment: Sorry @JDD, for not chatting. I am currently encountering problems in chat.stackoverflow.com with logging issues. will you chat here itself? or with email?

Comment: I've only been using pinpoint for about a week so I am not really an expert.  I'll check back in the chat if you can figure out how to post sometime, it is a public chat.

Comment: I will reply back in chat as soon as I fix logging issues. Thank you

Comment: @JDD, chat is working now. Will you able to chat for few minutes?